# MySql fails to be installed on Yosemite because of checksum check

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, homebrew

Every time I try to install mysql it fails because of SHA1. I know SHA1 and I know what that means but keep failing made me think that it may be because of some problem in homebrew. This is the error and it keep happening although I am sure that it's been downloaded correctly. I used `--verbose`!

```
$ brew install mysql --verbose
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/mysql-5.6.21.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
/usr/bin/curl -fLA Homebrew 0.9.5 (Ruby 2.0.0-481; Mac OS X 10.10) https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/mysql-5.6.21.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz -C 0 -o /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql-5.6.21.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz.incomplete
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- 0:00:02 --:--:-- 0
92 59.5M 92 55.0M 0 0 89188 0 0:11:40 0:10:47 0:00:53 0curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
Error: Failed to download resource "mysql"
Download failed: https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/mysql-5.6.21.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.21.tar.gz
/usr/bin/curl -fLA Homebrew 0.9.5 (Ruby 2.0.0-481; Mac OS X 10.10) http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.21.tar.gz -C 0 -o /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql-5.6.21.tar.gz.incomplete
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- 0:00:06 --:--:-- 0
100 5299 100 5299 0 0 534 0 0:00:09 0:00:09 --:--:-- 1690
==> Verifying mysql-5.6.21.tar.gz checksum
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: be068ba90953aecdb3f448b4ba1d35796eb799eb
Actual: f08be72b50917f121800d28c73f1406290936cb5
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql-5.6.21.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this myself and got the correct checksum.  Try downloading the file manually using `curl` or `wget` and check the checksum.  Check if a network proxy or something like that is mangling your downloads.

Comment: Thanks peter, I installed it using dmg file in mysql website.

Comment: Any way installing mysql was not the main issue for me here, installation failure was the issue.